# The method ... is undefined for the type

Tags: java, eclipse

При вызове метода возникает ошибка:

> The method setProduct(Product[]) is undefined for the type ProductList

вызов метода осуществляется здесь:

```
Product[] customerProducts = new Product[customerCatalog.size()];
customerCatalog.copyInto(customerProducts); 
productList.setProduct(customerProducts); // проблема здесь
```

сам метод:

```
public void setProduct(Product[] customerProducts){
    ProductList productList = new ProductList();
    productList = (ProductList) Arrays.asList(customerProducts);
}
```

а `ProductList` описан только в схеме:

```
<xs:complexType name="ProductList">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                This is a list of product types.
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
                name="Product" type="order:Product" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

что здесь не так?

Comment: Что такое  productList?

Answer (score 1):

Это значит

> "метод  *** не определён в классе (типе) ***"

Проверьте где именно у вас описан метод `setProduct`. Судя по ошибке и коду, он определён у вас не в классе `ProductList`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, судя по тегу "eclipse" необходимо очистить проект и сервер. У меня такое иногда бывает, что все классы поправил, но они каким-то образом не скомпилировались, по коду ошибки не подчёркивает, но нормально не работает.
Чтобы очистить проект нажмите project => clean.
Если запущен сервер, то его тоже можно почистить.